# Footnote friggeri-cv latex template

Tags: xetex, footnotes, friggeri-cv

I'm trying to customise the Friggeri-CV template.
I'd like to add a footnote on top of "Now".
I tried the following code:

```
\section{education}
\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2013--Now \footnote{An example footnote.}}
{PhD {\normalfont in Computer Science}}
{University, United Kingdom}
\end{entrylist}
```

The foot number appears on top of the world "Now", however there is no foot not at the bottom of the page. How can I modify the code in order to get the description at the bottom of the page?

Comment: You should always spoonfeed your audience. Provide [links to content that aren't part of a default distribution](https://github.com/afriggeri/cv) and include a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) rather than code snippets.

Answer (score 2):

The `entrylist` environment actually sets a `tabular`, and all `\footnote`s inside a `tabular` is gobbled. You have to set a manual `\footnotemark` and a separate `\footnotetext` *outside* the `entrylist` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{friggeri-cv}% https://github.com/afriggeri/cv

\begin{document}
\header{name}{surname}
       {occupation}

\section{education}
\begin{entrylist}
  %------------------------------------------------
  \entry
    {2013--Now \footnotemark}
    {PhD {\normalfont in Computer Science}}
    {University, United Kingdom}{}
\end{entrylist}
\footnotetext{An example footnote.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks! Sorry to not have posted the link to the material, it was my first post.

Comment: It appears in your screenshot, and also in my document when I compile it, that the line ist solid black, and not textcolored. How can I change it to fit the textcolor of the document?

Comment: @MaximMoloshenko: `friggeri-cv` does nothing to change the footnote rule. You can adjust the color by adding to your preamble `\let\oldfootnoterule\footnoterule
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\color{gray}\oldfootnoterule}` (possibly changing `gray` to match your needs; I chose `gray` since `friggeri-cv` uses this colour as a reference for `textcolor`).